# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT: Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sigabrt, touchesbegan

I've found this error when I am tapping to restart a game I have created. It is called in a different separate SKScene from GameScene and is written in touchesBegan(). Is there something missing in my code?

Here it is:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameOver: SKScene {
  override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    ...
  }
  override func touchesBegan() {
    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
  }
}





 _TFC13Penguin_Peril8GameOver12touchesBeganfS0_FTGVSs3SetCSo7UITouch_9withEventGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_ + 397
10  Penguin Peril                       0x0000000108a30cf2 _TToFC13Penguin_Peril8GameOver12touchesBeganfS0_FTGVSs3SetCSo7UITouch_9withEventGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_ + 98
11  SpriteKit                           0x000000010a835c4a -[SKView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 941
12  UIKit                               0x000000010aa52894 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 308
13  UIKit                               0x000000010aa53691 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
14  UIKit                               0x000000010aa05752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
15  UIKit                               0x000000010a9e0fcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a0380a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a02dfcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a02d483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a02ce98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e98dad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
21  UIKit                               0x000000010a9e6676 UIApplicationMain + 171
22  Penguin Peril                       0x0000000108a49afd main + 109
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cac092d start + 1
```

)
       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type  NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Look in the console at the bottom of Xcode. There should be more information shown

Comment: Ive looked there. I cant seen to figure out a solution.

Comment: Can you post what is show in the console output?

Comment: Included it in an edit.